# Android data binding, Radio Button not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, radio-button

I have some RadioButtons and I want them to be checked/unchecked as the model changes, using Data Binding.
I managed to set up an EditText and it is working fine.
Anyway, the RadioButtons behave as the android:checked property wouldn't be there.

```
<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/radio_kitchen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kitchen"
    android:checked="@{radiator.room==@string/kitchen?true:false}"
/>
```

Comment: You probably intend .equals instead of ==

Comment: I also tried .equals, anyway i'm not sure it is supported

Comment: This should work: "@{radiator.room.equals(@string/kitchen)}". If not, please file a bug because it should work.

Comment: is `radiator.room` returning string resource id or string?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Perfect answer! It took me an hour to analyze this..

Answer (score 4):

This is what I am currently doing for this:

```
        <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> car.setModel(@string/car_model_toyota)}"
        android:checked="@{car.model.equals(@string/car_model_toyota)}"
        android:text="@string/car_model_toyota"/>
```

It's cheating since I am kind of giving some code logic to the View... but at least I don't have to implement an onchange listener on every single radiogroup and I still get the binding to happen...

Unless someone correct me and gives me a more ethic and professional solution I think I am going to stick with this one.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create custom ids for each radio button and use android:checkedButton of radiogroup to retain checked state of radio button via two way data binding.
For value of radio button you can use android:onClick attribute to have specific value according to your business logic**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:checkedButton="@={signUpModel.genderId}"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerGender"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:onClick="@{()->signUpModel.setGender(@string/cd_female)}"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gender_cta_selector"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_gender_female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_female"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="@{()->signUpModel.setGender(@string/cd_male)}"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_gender_male"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gender_cta_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_male"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**ids.xml(Inside values)**

```
<resources>
    <item name="female" type="id" format="string"/>
    <item name="male" type="id" format="string"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RadioGroup ...>     
 <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/male"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="male"
                                android:value="male"
                                android:onClick="@{()->user.setGender(@string/male)}"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

On string item set this works on my end

```
<string name="female">female</string>
<string name="male">male</string>
```

> 

Answer (score -1):

This answer might be late but others those who are facing this issue can try out:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Iron Man"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Batman"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Activity:

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.iron_man:
            if (checked)
                // Iron man is the best!
            break;
        case R.id.batman:
            if (checked)
                // Batman rocks!
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the method that I found on Android Developers [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton#java).

Comment: you haven't even used databinding in your answer.