# Visibility not working in data binding android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-databinding

I am using the latest data binding in android using android studio 2.1.
using the visibility tag as describe in the below code getting an error as

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   / data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. View is missing it
>   file:D:\HP\HealthPortal_Android\Code\app\src\main\res\layout\cardview_image_twotextview.xml
>   loc:68:90 - 68:93
>   \ data binding error

```
   <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/card_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/card_title"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/carview_margin"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_image"
                        android:text="@{toolsAndTrackersCards.subtitle}"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:visibility="@{toolsAndTrackersCards.subtitle.equals(@string/Empty_String) ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                        />
```

Done some google not abel to find the solution. The **@string/Empty_String** is define as empty string "" in string.xml file. where I am doing wrong.

[Android data binding, Radio Button not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416870/android-data-binding-radio-button-not-updating)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this to your `cardview_image_twotextview.xml`:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <!--your variables-->
</data>
```

Comment: I was just making a variable of type view and didn't know that it was important to import it. Thanks for the solution. Saved me a lot of time and bad code.

Answer (score 13):

To hide a view if the string is **empty**, use the below expression in data binding

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.test.model.Item" />
</data>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{item.title}"
    android:visibility='@{item.title.equals("") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}'/>
```

**NOTE:** need to use outer single quote string in order to use double quote to 
 represent the empty string

If you want to check for **null** and **empty**, use the below code :

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.test.model.Item" />
</data>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{item.title}"
    android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(item.title) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Zero or more import elements may be used inside the data element.
>   These allow easy reference to classes inside your layout file, just
>   like in Java.

you need to import View class inorder to use its properties.

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

you can also refer official [DataBinding guideline](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html#layout_details).